# Angular 7 - ngForm, ngSubmit - submitting old values

Tags: angular, angular7

I am using form in Angular 7 as below

```
<form #payForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(payForm, $event)" method="POST" action="POST URL HERE">
      <input type="hidden" name="requestParameter" [value]="stringToSend" />
      <div class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" class="btn blbtn text-uppercase px-5 py-2 rounded my-3" value="Pay Now">
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <a [routerLink]="['/logout']" class="onerem ltbl-link w-auto d-inline-block">Cancel</a>
      </div>
</form>
```

Here "stringToSend" is getting calculated each time there is some user action like different plan selection or coupon selection. But when he finally clicks on "Pay Now" button, then I want to submit form to the POST URL from my angular component, so I am calling using `ngForm` with `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(payForm, $event)"`

Below is my code from controller

```
onSubmit(form: any, clkEvent: any): void {

// some database inserts before form submit
stringToSend = newCalculatedValue;   // setting stringToSend to new calculated value

clkEvent.target.submit();   // actual form submit from controller

}
```

But when I submit this form, the last value of `stringToSend` is getting send with form as form data not the latest one which I am calculating inside `onSubmit()` function.

Before setting latest value I consoled it, it's showing fine, but with form last value is submitting which is my Problem in angular. I also tried `[(ngModel)]` but still no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: I searched for changeDetectorRef and created reference in constructor and used like  ref.detectChanges(),  but don't know how it works as my issue was unsolved

Comment: Can you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) repo for the same.

Comment: Code is very lengthy....and also it's confidential that's why I tried to provide the exact issue what I am facing...@Pankaj Have you faced this kind of issue earlier ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for not picking up latest value is how angular bindings work. The `input` element is binded to `stringToSend` variable, but before angular gets a chance to update the bindings to the actual DOM node, the form gets submitted. One way to fix this issue, is to delay the `form` posting in the next event loop cycle (eg. using a `setTimeout`).

```
onSubmit(form: any, clkEvent: any): void {

    // some database inserts before form submit
    stringToSend = newCalculatedValue;   // setting stringToSend to new calculated value
    setTimeout(()=>{
       clkEvent.target.submit();   // actual form submit from controller
    } , 0);
}
```

However, the above solution would a hacky way to fix the issue. Ideally, form submission should be delegated to a service.

Refer to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview) for some best practices when dealing with `form` controls.